# How to change the loading circle spinner size in android

Tags: android, spinner

In my android application, i am using spinner and it's work during the data retrieving time from server but it's too large. how can i change the size of the spinner![enter image description here][1]

i need to reduce the size of circle spinner. like medium size icon not small one. it's large size. i want know about how to design custom circle spinner

Answer (score 0):

to change spinner size change "android:padding"

you can make custom spinner like this:

```
<TextView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="left"  
android:textColor="#FF0000"         
android:padding="2dip"
/>
```

Now use this file to show your spinner items like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```